# Which utility to use to find difference between two files

Tags: file, difference

If the contents of the two files are:

```
file1         file2
corn          fish 
flakes        corn
butter        flakes 
mayo          butter
```

How would I find entries that are in file1 and not file2(mayo)? I do not want to see entries that are in file2 but are in file1. Files may not be sorted same way.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Unix, use this command: [diff manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)

```
$ diff <file1> <file2>
```

in case of windows:

```
FC file1 file2
```

Comment: this is a two way check, i only need to check 1 file against second file